# How can I store the resulting sum values to memory RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

In RISC-V, What code can I use to extract and store values to memory?

For example, can I use:

```
sw s1, 0(t6)        #stores updated value at t6
```

Will this save the result to a new memory address `t6` or will it put it back and store it in the array? Hence all array values are stored in `s1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RV32I is a load-store architecture, where only load and store instructions access memory and arithmetic instructions only operate on CPU registers. Load and store instructions transfer a value between the registers and memory.

LOADS

```
 imm[11:0]  | rs1  | funct3 |  rd  | opcode
    12      |  5   |   3    |  5   |   7
offset[11:0]| base | width  | dest |  LOAD
```

STORES

```
 imm[11:5]  | rs2 | rs1 | funct3 |  imm[4:0]  | opcode
      7     |  5  |  5  |    3   |      5     |   7
offset[11:5]| src |base | width  | offset[4:0]| STORE
```

Instructions:

```
Load  Byte          LB        rd,rs1,imm
Load  Halfword      LH        rd,rs1,imm 
Load  Word          L{W|D|Q}  rd,rs1,imm 
Load  Byte Unsigned LBU       rd,rs1,imm 
Load  Half Unsigned L{H|W|D}U rd,rs1,imm 

Store Byte          SB        rs1,rs2,imm 
Store Halfword      SH        rs1,rs2,imm 
Store Word          S{W|D|Q}  rs1,rs2,imm
```

Where rs - register source, rd - register destination, imm - immediate value.

In other words we just load and store data from and to a memory. If we want to load from memory we should use:

```
lw  t1, 28(a0)
```

Where t1 - temporary register, destination of memory read operation at address a0 with offset of 28. If a0 will be equal to 4000, the address where we will read from will be 4028.

Storage in the same way, but vice versa:

```
sw  t1, 28(a0)
```

Storing value from t1 register to memory address a0+28.
Highly recommends align data to it's data type, otherwise it can be runs very slow!
Also for RV64 we just extends the address space to 64 bits. The rest is almost the same.
Try to look this document, it very useful for riscv programmers:
https://riscv.org//wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf